# How to change vertical alignment of text in a paragraph

Tags: paragraphs, alignment, center

I am trying to format a line of text that has two different sized fonts such that the vertical alignment of the smaller sized text is based off the larger sized text.

In one instance I'd like the smaller text to be vertically centered on the larger text, and in another I'd like the smaller text topline to be aligned with the larger text topline.

To my admittedly very limited understanding, this should translate to to changing a paragraph parameter to change the paragraphs vertical alignment to either "center" or "topline".

[image]

Comment: This is possible, by using `minipage` environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[t]` (`[b]` to align on first or last baseline, to adjust so the tops of the letters align, you can shift with `\raisebox` by more or less the difference in size of capital letters (what looks right depends on how many capital or lowercase letters are in the line)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}



1 \parbox{3cm}{\Huge Big text}
1 some text some text some text some text some text

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip


2 \parbox[t]{3cm}{\Huge Big text}
2 some text some text some text some text some text

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip


3 \raisebox{-10pt}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\Huge Big text}}
3 some text some text some text some text some text

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip


4 \parbox{3cm}{\Huge Big text more text}
4 some text some text some text some text some text

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip


5 \parbox[t]{3cm}{\Huge Big text more text}
5 some text some text some text some text some text

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

6 \raisebox{-10pt}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\Huge Big text more text}}
6 some text some text some text some text some text

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It led me to finding and using the [pbox package](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pbox/pbox.pdf) which allows for variable width horizontal text.

Comment: @atommclain pbox is just a tabular environment actually but OK.

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to compute the needed `\raisebox` distance for samples, it would probably be easier to print out the value and use that.  Note that `\strut` is slightly larger than the sample text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\bigtext}
\newsavebox{\smalltext}

\begin{document}
\sbox\bigtext{\huge BIG TEXT}%
\sbox\smalltext{Some text}%
\hrule
%\strut% will lower the text relative to the line
\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\smalltext-\ht\bigtext}{\usebox\bigtext}
\usebox{\smalltext} Some text. 
\the\dimexpr \ht\smalltext-\ht\bigtext\relax
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

A notion of “vertically centered” is not well defined unless all characters have no descenders and the same height (that is, for capital letters).

The main problem is in how the eye perceives the characters: probably descenders would be ignored, but ascenders far away might make for “wrong” centering. See the following examples:

[image]

In either case, the small text is centered with respect to the height of the big text, but the bottom one doesn't *look* like it is. Here I add leader rules to show the business:

[image]

With the rules the centering appears right also in the second example, but without them the eye is misguided by the white space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}

\newcommand{\bigandcentered}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{\huge\sffamily #1}%
  \sbox2{\sffamily #2}%
  \usebox{0}\quad
  \raisebox{\dimeval{(\ht0-\ht2)/2}}{\usebox{2}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\bigandcentered{Hey}{centered}

\bigskip

\bigandcentered{Ace}{full hand}

\end{document}
```

Top alignment suffers from the same problem: in a font like Helvetica or Arial that you seem to want, ascenders have different heights.

[image]

This doesn't really look like “aligned at the top”, but it is!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}

\newcommand{\topandbig}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{\sffamily #1}%
  \sbox2{\huge\sffamily #2}%
  \raisebox{\dimeval{\ht2-\ht0}}{\usebox{0}}\quad
  \usebox{2}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\topandbig{Text at the top}{Big text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer and providing context which potentially answers the question behind the question and detangling the thorny area of "do what I mean" vs "do what I say".